# Error : list.remove(x) : x not in list, I don't understand why

Tags: python-3.x, list, valueerror

I'm working on a little text-based game and having a problem with removing element from a list.
Here is a code to run that throws the error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in the list` but I don't see why.

```
LVL = 'lvl'
DAMAGE = 'damage'

Items = {
    'Sword':{
        LVL : 1,
        DAMAGE : 5,
    },

    'Wand':{
        LVL : 1,
        DAMAGE : 3,
    },
}

class player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []

class item():
    def __init__(self, name: str, **kwarg):
        self.name = name
        self.dmg = kwarg.get(DAMAGE)
        self.lvl = kwarg.get(LVL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = player()
    for i in Items.keys():
        it = item(i, **Items[i])
        user.inventory.append(it)

    # check user's inventory
    print('Inventory after append items :')
    for i in user.inventory:
        print(i)

    # let's say i want the user to drop items
    items_name = [i for i in Items.keys()]
    items_to_drop = [item(i, **Items[i]) for i in items_name]
    for i in items_to_drop:
        user.inventory.remove(i)
```

My guess is that even if the items from `user.inventory` are *the same* as those in `items_to_drop`, the program sees it as two different variables. In which case I do not see how to perform what I want, that is removing items from `user.inventory` given a list filled with items to remove (because I cannot loop over `user.inventory` directly right ?)

I apologize if this question has been answered before. I have searched for it but with no success.

Comment: How do you think Python compares two instances of `item`?

Comment: @timgeb does this mean I have to code it ? Like overwrite `__eq__` method in the class `item` ? If not, I guess I don't know..

Comment: You're on the right track, customize `__eq__`!

Answer (score 1):

In the end, as suggested in comment, I had to overwrite `__eq__()` method of class `item` so that Python *sees* if two **same** items are actually in both `user.inventory` and `items_to_drop`. It works !

If needed, I simply did

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.name == other.name
```

Comment: Note that currently `dmg` and `lvl` can be different for two items Python considers equal. (But maybe that's intended.)

Comment: @timgeb yes, it is in my case. But thank you for the specification !

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution:

```
    # let's say i want the user to drop items
    items_name = [i for i in Items.keys()]
    items_to_drop = [item(i, **Items[i]) for i in items_name]
    for i in items_to_drop:
        try:
            user.inventory.remove(i)
        except:
            continue
```

another one and better one:

```
    # let's say i want the user to drop items
    items_name = [i for i in Items.keys()]
    items_to_drop = [item(i, **Items[i]) for i in items_name]
    invetory_copy = inventory.copy()
    for i in inventory:
        if i in items_to_drop:
            inventory_copy.remove(i)
    inventory = inventory_copy
```

Comment: Isn't it not recommended to loop over a list while changing it ? Plus, in the first example, I do not see clearly the difference... The program will go for the `except` part directly without changing `user.inventory` . As for the second, I have tried it and it does not work. I think is linked to what @timgeb suggested.